# how do i deal with internet explorers lack of functionality?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome

http://pastebin.com/FctZD1j8
this script makes a right frame and a left frame with css.

in chrome and firefox, its normal, i have stuff in the left frame, stuff in the right frame, and stuff in the main content. but in IE the main content is in the left frame in kind of like a html Iframe. any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this jsFiddle will be easier to manipulate and play with: http://jsfiddle.net/3wV5M/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably the quirks mode that causes that. I tried it standards compliant mode in IE6, IE7, IE8 and IE9, and it works fine:

http://jsfiddle.net/Xugj4/1/

You might want to use an older HTML version if you want to support IE6, like HTML 4.01. IE6 doesn't know what XHTML is.

Comment: i took out the quirk mode comment and it still does that. 
and how do i make the html version older?

Comment: If you are serving your xhtml as MIME type `text/html` then IE6 will understand it fine (provided you have a space before `/>`).

Comment: @johnhunter: Well, it's rather that IE6 will accept it, and think that it's just broken HTML code...

Comment: @bzupnick: View the source code of the preview frame of the working jsFiddle example, and see if you catch any important differences with your page. Validate the code of your page to see if there is something that is broken: http://validator.w3.org/ You can use a different doctype tag if you want to change the HTML version: http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, my IE8 displays it just fine. Which browser versions are you referring to?

Have you tried using floats instead of your absolutes and fixed positioned elements.

Maybe explain a bit the rationale behind this strange positioning. What would you like to achieve?

### Screenshot in IE8

This is how it looks like in IE8 on my machine. I can see content being displayed in the middle `div` just fine. It even scrolls as expected. Does it look right to you as well or should it look differently?
[image: Display in IE8]

Comment: im testing it on IE9 and it totally shoves everything in the left frame, heres a pic of it: http://tinypic.com/r/rk9281/7

this is how chrome succesfully views it: http://tinypic.com/r/ohtg1i/7

Comment: @bzupnick: What about other IE versions? It obviously displays as expected, so I can dismiss the IE9 just because it's not yet RTM and wouldn't even bother. If all final version browsers display correctly then it's fine.

Comment: @bzupnick: strange positioning with having two absolutely positioned elements and the main one that's positioned as fixed but scrollable.

Comment: @bzupnick: I attached a screenshot from IE8. Seems fine by me. http://jsfiddle.net/3wV5M/1/

Comment: @bzupnick: Well check the screenshot. Is it correct or not? If it is then I can deduct that it works as expected. Screenshot was made in IE8 (exact version being 8.0.7600.16385)